# overwrite then append output of a cron job each time it runs

Tags: redirect, cron

I know you can redirect the output of a cronjob via ">" to overwrite and ">>" to append. However, I was wondering if there is anyway to get the output from a cronjob to overwrite the log file each time the job is run, but then append the output for that particular job run?

When you use > it overwrites anything previously each time there is a in the output of the command linebreak, so you don't see historical output from that particular job.

Comment: Not sure i understand the question, can you give an example how the log file would look? e.g after a first run and then a second run.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you want to create a new log file everytime the job is run, so in crontab you use ">" as

```
* * * * /home/myhome/some_cron_job.sh > /home/myhome/cron_job_output
```

Now, within some_cron_job.sh, you use ">>" to append to the log file

```
(within shell script)
echo "Testing" >> /home/myhome/cron_job_output
```

Does that help ?